# Row of Images With PDFMake?

Tags: javascript, typescript, web, pdfmake

I have tried :

```
    {
        image: 'sampleImage.jpg',

    },
    {
        image: 'sampleImage.jpg',

    },
```

and :

```
{
    image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
    image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
},
```

does not provide the result. Is there an option to disable the newline each image content appears to create through the PDFMake library, or how could one go about making say, two images appear on the same row?

This is assuming the image widths are small enough to fit on a line on a standard 8x11 page.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  pdfmake columns for the requried functionallity sample:

```
       {
        columns: [
          {
              image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
              width: 200
          },

          {
               image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
               width: 200
          },

          {
              image: 'sampleImage.jpg',
              width: 200
          }
        ],
        columnGap: 10
    },
```